# 2 Select with same options, alerting when it is already selected at the first Select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having a hard time with this, basically I have 2 Select with same options. The 2 Select Inputs named as **registrationdiscounttype1** and **registrationdiscounttype2**

So First I choose a discount for **registrationdiscounttype1** then if I will add a discount for **registrationdiscounttype2** if the option is already selected in discount number 1 it will show an error that will say the discount is already selected.

I've already made a javascript based on what I've search so far, but I can't make it work, can you help me what is wrong with my code, or what should I use?

This is the sample photo
[image]

```js
// Change in Discount 2 

$("#registrationdiscounttype2").unbind('change').bind('change', function() 

if ($('#registrationdiscounttype2').closest('table').find('option[value=' + $('#registrationdiscounttype1').val() + ']:selected').length > 1)
{
alert('Discount is already selected, Please choose another one');   
}

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="registrationdiscounttype1" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Discount 1: </label>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <select class="form-control" name="registrationdiscounttype1" id="registrationdiscounttype1">
    <option value="">Select Discount </option>
    <?php foreach ($discounttypeData as $discounttype)
    {
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $discounttype['discounttype_id']; ?>"> <?php echo $discounttype['discounttype_name']; ?> </option>

    <?php 
    } 
    ?>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="registrationdiscounttype2" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Discount 2: </label>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
  <select class="form-control" name="registrationdiscounttype2" id="registrationdiscounttype2">
  <option value="">Select Discount </option>
  <?php foreach ($discounttypeData as $discounttype)
  {
  ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $discounttype['discounttype_id']; ?>"> <?php echo $discounttype['discounttype_name']; ?> </option>

  <?php 
  } 
  ?>
  </select>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I am wrong please inform me but I can't see `closest("table")`.

Comment: It comes from another code, that I just tried to use, I don't know what's the right syntax for this as I have tried many others. You can suggest any thing that is related if you know one. It's not necesarily you need to use that.

Comment: I'm sorry but, if it comes from another code where does this validation fires?

Comment: It works in dynamically added row, and shows if it is already selected in the Options. But It doesn't work in this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

u can try

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#registrationdiscounttype2").unbind('change').bind('change', function() {

  if ($('#registrationdiscounttype2').val() == $('#registrationdiscounttype1').val())
  {
  alert('Discount is already selected, Please choose another one');   
  }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="registrationdiscounttype1" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Discount 1: </label>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <select class="form-control" name="registrationdiscounttype1" id="registrationdiscounttype1">
    <option value="">Select Discount </option>
    <option value="1">1 </option>
    <option value="2">2 </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="registrationdiscounttype2" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Discount 2: </label>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
  <select class="form-control" name="registrationdiscounttype2" id="registrationdiscounttype2">
  <option value="">Select Discount </option>
    <option value="1">1 </option>
    <option value="2">2 </option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group" id="result">
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with an example solution (if **select element are siblings**) https://jsfiddle.net/pvchxyup/1/

```js
$('select').change(function(){
 if($(this).val() === $(this).siblings('select').val() ){
   console.log("Same value!!!");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="test1">Test 1</option>
  <option value="test2">Test 2</option>
  <option value="test5">Test 5</option>
</select>

<select>
  <option value="test1">Test 1</option>
  <option value="test2">Test 2</option>
  <option value="test7">Test 7</option>
</select>
```

If your **element** are **not siblings**, then follow **https://jsfiddle.net/pvchxyup/2/**

```js
$('select').change(function(){
 if($('#select1').val() === $('#select2').val() ){
   console.log("Same value!!!");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select id="select1">
    <option value="test1">Test 1</option>
    <option value="test2">Test 2</option>
    <option value="test5">Test 5</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div>
  <select id="select2">
    <option value="test1">Test 1</option>
    <option value="test2">Test 2</option>
    <option value="test7">Test 7</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Nope this will not work, because you have same name of "select1" in 2 different Select, it should be "select1" and "select2". But the code you suggest will not work.

Comment: @Cecatrix... It's not name it's id.. I know it should be unique... but in my JS code I'm not referring anywhere... Did you check that???

Comment: My mistake it's id, but I've tried your code and it doesn't work because it needs 2 same id's. Mine has 2 different id's.

Comment: maybe try using 2 different id's

Comment: In your case, it will not work because select elements are not siblings...

Answer (score 0):

No need to use bind, simple and easy way to do that.
Try this:

```js
$("#registrationdiscounttype2").change(function(){
 if($(this).val()==$('#registrationdiscounttype1').val()){
   alert("Already Selected");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="registrationdiscounttype1" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Discount 1: </label>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <select class="form-control" name="registrationdiscounttype1" id="registrationdiscounttype1">
    <option value="">Select Discount </option>
    <option value="sel1">sel1</option>
    <option value="sel2">sel2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="registrationdiscounttype2" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Discount 2: </label>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
  <select class="form-control" name="registrationdiscounttype2" id="registrationdiscounttype2">
  <option value="">Select Discount </option>
  <option value="sel1">sel1</option>
  <option value="sel2">sel2</option>
  </select>
</div>
```